# What is included in the notion 'browser-cache'?

Tags: browser, cache

What is exactly included in the notion `browser-cache`?
Does the notion `browser-cache` include in itself:

- cookies
- web-site-data
- browser-settings
- history
- bookmarks

Or the notion `browser-cache` includes only already resolved dns-names and certain list of already visited web-pages/urls?

Comment: The "browser cache" is typically anything the browser has encountered that it thinks may need in the future (for "convenience" or to generally speed up browsing) and thus often stores automatically. Of the items you list, perhaps only bookmarks and browser settings would be excluded, since they are typically added/altered by users, not the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser cache contains URL, contents and time.
It does not contain the cookies, browser-settings, history or bookmarks,
as these are stored in separate containers.

The following image of the cache metadata in Chrome is taken from the
article
[View Cache data](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cache/):

[image]

Comment: does the answer also apply to firefox?

Comment: It applies to all browsers.

Comment: would it be correct if we say that superuser.com is a domain-name and url simultaneously?

Comment: @ccsann: No : `superuser.com` is a domain-name, but `https://superuser.com` is a URL. The domain is kept in a DNS cache, while the URL is kept in the browser's cache.

Comment: and the dns-cache is a file/s that is read by the locale dns-client ( dnsmasq or systemd-resolved )?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: 'The browser cache contains URL ... ' are the cached URLs ( in the browser's cache ) already resolved into IPs or they are not resolved into IPs?

Comment: The entire page is kept in the browser's cache. The idea is to avoid repeating internet requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138420/discussion-between-ccsann-and-harrymc).